# Is there a collection like "Thisdocument.Variables" (from Word-VBA) in Excel-VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I wanted to store a variable in the workbook, without showing it in any sheet.

On MS-Word-VBA that can be made using the collection `Document.Variables` but that doesn't exist in Excel-VBA.

Is there any other alternative to do this?

Comment: In Excel you can also use a Name to store a value

Comment: Or you can store them in BuiltinDocumentProperties or CustomDocumentProperties, as appropriate, or even on a hidden worksheet.

Comment: `CustomDocumentProperties` resolves the question, thank you. The question was answered in another post...